# Producing just a tight picture, is there a replacement for \documentclass{minimal}?

Tags: document-classes, minimal

I want to produce a picture in `PDF` format using `pdflatex`, with nothing else in the page but the picture, so I decided to use the document class `minimal`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\input{file_produced_by_graphics_program}
\end{document}
```

But the `\input` file contains labels in the form of `$\cal{A}$` and when I run `pdflatex` on the example input above I have

```
...
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cal 
...
```

**My question** is twofold

- may I use a different document class that defines `\cal` but doesn't put extraneous stuff on the page?
- may I load something or define a new command, so that I can use `\cal` inside a `minimal` document?

An extra question is, are there other similar gaps in `minimal` functionality?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Comment: You likely want the `standalone` class.

Comment: When I type `texdoc standalone`, it opens the documentation file near the end, a clear sign that a past self was wiser than the present one... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `standalone` class will even crop the PDF file for you, with customizable borders.

---

You should never use the `minimal` class, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided), but you should never use `\cal` as well.

It is true that `\cal` still works in the standard classes, but only for back compatibility; the command has been deprecated since 1995.

If you insist on using it, at least use it properly:

```
${\cal A}$
```

You may be very surprised if you try something like `$\cal{A}_m$`, producing

[image]

Do yourself a favor and prefer typing the longer, but safer,

```
$\mathcal{A}_m$
```